# Samba not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, samba

I installed Samba, and edited smb.conf. Then I typed the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

The response I got was

> sudo: /etc/init.d/samba: command not
>   found

So now what?

Edit: 
If I do sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart, I get the following message:

> Rather than invoking init scripts
>   through /etc/init.d, use the
>   service(8) utility, e.g. service smbd
>   restart
>
> Since the script you are attempting to
>   invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job, you may also use the
>   restart(8) utility, e.g. restart smbd
>   smbd start/running, process 9265

Comment: see my updated answer!

Comment: /etc/init.d/samba restart works very well on 9.10. I just had the issue, and it came with the upgrade to 10.04. It just changed to smbd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$ sudo su
# /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

and let me know if that works...

**UPDATE**

Then try the following:

```
$ sudo restart smbd
```

Comment: It says bash: /etc/init.d/samba: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

There are no `/etc/init.d/samba` initscript in the [`samba` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/samba/filelist); use `sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart` instead.

Comment: Odd... `sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart` works with me...

Comment: When I tried that I got a message, which I posted in the original question.

Comment: @awakeFromNib: first, even through it printed the message, the script actually ran. Second, if you don't want to see it, just use `sudo restart smbd`.

Answer (score 0):

### update for who using `Raspberry Pi`

1. `samba` command not found

```sh
$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/samba: command not found
```

2. find out the new service name of `samba`

```sh
$ ls -al /etc/init.d/ | grep -E "\ss"
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2259 Aug  1  2022 samba-ad-dc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2224 Apr 15  2018 saned
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2061 Aug  1  2022 smbd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4056 Jul  2  2022 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1030 Jan 14  2023 sudo
```

3. restart `smbd` service

```sh
$ sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
Restarting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.service.

# OR
$ sudo systemctl restart smbd
# OR
$ sudo systemctl restart smbd.service
```

> screenshot

[image]

### refs

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units